# Sign in with Instagram

Tags: php, authentication, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I need to make sign in with Instagram on my web site.
But its looks impossible in Instargam Graph API.

I tried to to a sign in with Facebook and take information about Instagram,
but i do not know how.
I just need to have a real not fake accounts username. That is all.
How can i do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What do you mean by *it looks impossible ...*? I feel you should continue your (re)search before posting it here. I'm sure there is alot of example on the web. For next time, please feel free to look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm just familar with oauth which is havily related to that what you are trying to do. It seems that there is an oauth api which you can try to use: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: thank you for answer. But is it new information? I mean In March Instagram API will be stopped.  before i used
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize

Answer (score 1):

The suggested answers are correct. If you want to use the Instagram Graph API to login, you actually use a "Connect with Facebook" button because the Insta Graph API is powered by Facebook's OAuth.

A lot of the old Instagram (legacy) API is being sunset. You may still be able to build a simple OAuth, but it won't really give you much data beyond an auth token.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: Thank you! 
Do you mean, that i still will be able to use OAuth and settings from your link?

Comment: @MarzhanBulkayeva, yes, if you want to use OAuth from the instagram link, you will still be able to use that for basic profile data from Instagram. You just won't get metrics and private data which instead comes from the Facebook Graph API.

Answer (score 1):

It appears all of the links above are broken - as far as I can tell, as of 2021-11-01 this can only be done via Facebook, still researching to see if Oauth with Instagram credentials VIA Facebook is possible.